# Extend Yii Autoloader to load classes named using the Zend convention

Tags: zend-framework, yii, kohana, autoload

I'm currently experimenting with the Yii framework and have come across a slight snag. Having come from being a heavy user of Kohana, I'm used to naming classes according to the Zend convention. For example:

```
new Example_Foo_Bar;
```

would reference a class in the path:

```
Example/Foo/Bar.php
```

However, in the Yii framework the autoloader logic expects the path to be:

```
Example/Foo/Example_Foo_Bar.php
```

before it would be able to locate and load the class file, which of course is not ideal for my use-case. I have tried using namespaces with Yii which worked up to a point, but when I try to reference a Yii native class such as a model from within a namespaced class, it trys to load the model from the current namespace which is expected but certainly not what I'm after.

Does anyone know how to extend the Yii autoloading mechanism to be able to load classes using its own convention and using the Zend convention as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension that does this: [zendautoloader](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/zendautoloader)

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I did see the Zend autoloader but for my use case I am not using the Zend framework, I'm creating my own custom classes using the Zend naming convention. I'm sure the zend autoloader extension could be adapted to my use-case but requires quite abit of tweaking. I was hoping there would be a more straight-forward approach.

Comment: That autoloader I think is just perfect for you: Ability to load custom code that is using Zend class naming convention but with different prefix. Did you tried using it?

Comment: Actually I didn't try it and used an alternative solution that involved including the classes using the Yii import feature; However now that you mention it, it seems that the plugin is capable of handling my use-case so I'm going to accept your answer! Thanks